# Aligning floating parts of a form field

Tags: html, css, positioning, css-float

I have a list of form fields contained within `ul` and `li` structure. I have simplified my markup to focus on a problem I have.

Here's the markup:

```
<ul>
<li class="multiplechoice">
   <fieldset>
     <legend>my label</legend>
     <div class="description">My description</div>

          <ul>        
            <li>
              <button value="asdf" readonly="readonly"></button>
              <label>test12</label>
             </li>
             <li>
               <button value="0" readonly="readonly"></button>
               <label for="test23">test23</label> </li>
           </ul>

    </fieldset>
</li>
</ul>
```

And the CSS I have so far:

```
legend{
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.description{
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

ul{
    float: left;
}
```

Note: The `div` with the class `description` can either not exist, contain no text inside or contain text.

What I wish to do is to have the legend and the description both floated to the left. The description should be underneath the legend. The `ul` containing the buttons should be seperated by a margin from those floated items, be aligned to the top of the first float and aligned vertically.

Here's a picture showing the current state of things:
[image]

I have been trying all sorts of floats and positioning, but can't seem to get there. Can anyone advice as to how the desired result can be achieved?

I am looking for a CSS only solution, preferably no javascript please :)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eHEcJ/

Comment: That would be why 'GOD' invented tables

Comment: take a look at [this forked fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NBkmx/). BTW you are missing the point in having a `fieldset`, and you are mistaken be referring a generic `ul` in the CSS.

Comment: @web_bod - tables are not semantically correct for layouts. since 1921.

Comment: @EliranMalka: Can you explain what is the right way to implement the field set? If you meant that the `form` tags are missing, it's because I have removed them as that is just 1 field in a form a a heaps of other fields :)

Comment: i was referring to your expectations from the `fieldset`'s `legend` layout. in your second illustration the expected layout is inconceivable.

Comment: @EliranMalka: Can you expand on why it is inconceivable and what would be the correct markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just getting rid of the float on the `ul` and making it an `inline-block`:

```
legend{
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.description{
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

ul{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

And the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BU57V/

Answer (score 0):

Move the `description` into the `label` and you can remove the `clear:both` and `float:left` attributes from it - the description is now part of the left floating label, so it should work. Make the `Description` `display:block`

```
<style>
.myLabel{
    float: left;
    width: 80px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.description{
    width: 80px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    display:block;
}

ul{
    float: left;
}

</style>
<fieldset>
  <ul>
    <li class="multiplechoice">
          <label class="myLabel">my label
            <span class="description">some description</span>
          </label>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <button value="asdf" readonly="readonly"></button>
              <label>test12</label>
             </li>
             <li>
               <button value="0" readonly="readonly"></button>
               <label for="test23">test23</label> </li>
           </ul>
     </li>
</ul></fieldset>
```

*Had some problems with the final  tag not rendering.*

Comment: Unfotunately, a legend cannot contain a div according to the HTML5 validator :(

Comment: So, replace the div with another element and make it `diplay:block`

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that will help, as stated above you don't always need a table to align fields.  Found out by trial and error as I am trying to create a Header for a report; i am a beginner with HTML so this might not be the most elegant solution.

[image]